# How to set a value for an URL placeholder on building the app?

Tags: appgyver

I have an AppGyver App with a URL placeholder. Testing the REST API with setting the placeholder is working fine. But how to set the placeholder when building the app for distribution?
And how to find out with which Android versions the build is compatible?

When I built the app, I always got an empty placeholder value inserted and thus connect the REST API to a wrong resource / service.